# Do people in Gotham know that Batman doesn't kill?

Tags: dc, batman

Batman is the symbol that Gotham needs, a shadow that brings justice and fear to  criminals. You don't want to be a criminal in Gotham, because Batman is somewhere around and could catch you at any time. This is very well represented in Nolan's trilogy, for example.

Also (in most versions of Batman), as a symbol of justice, Batman is bound by the rule of not killing his enemies. Rather, he tries to arrest them, so that they can go to jail or Arkham City.

Are criminals, and more generally normal folks in Gotham, aware of Batman's "no killing" rule? Some high-profile criminals accidentally died when fighting the Dark Knight, and their deaths were reported on by the news media, so from a layman's perspective, it could be unclear if Batman meant for them to be killed or not.

I am asking for answers from any media or continuity where the "no killing" rule is thoroughly applied.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Nolan's trilogy? Batman not always had 'No Killing' rule in comics or Burton's Movies

Comment: I am asking for answers from any media or continuity where the "no killing" rule is thoroughly applied. The mention of Nolan's trilogy was just an example of how people in Gotham are generally perceiving Batman.

Comment: Going by the last sentence, I'd say yes - the scope of the question is limited to works in which Batman has a rule about not killing, otherwise the question is moot. (EDIT: ninja'd by author)

Comment: I dont think he ever made a public announcement in any continuity. So as your question states itself, nromal folks will always be in doubt.

Comment: They've been given the impression he was responsible for a number of deaths, including Harvey Dent in Nolan's version. I figure they wouldn't be so quick to condemn him if they truly believed he had a 'No Killing' policy. I'm more curious if they get compensated when his batmobile is in "intimidate mode" and trashes public and private property

Comment: There is a lot of myth surrounding batman, the criminals probably can't tell which is true and which is not. Many don't even believe he is human. Some think he is some kind of demon.

Answer (score 5):

**I doubt that normal folks in Gotham are aware of his rule as he never made a public announcement. Even if they heard of it from someone, there are so many incidents where Batman killed someone accidentally that they will always be in doubt.**

While Batman stopped killing ever since the 1943 due to becoming a kid friendly character, despite the fact that he got his moral code he resumed occasional killing starting with the late 1960's in Brave and The Bold # 83 in which he destroys a German plane using a hand grenade and uses dynamite to blow up a convoy of German soldiers as they are crossing a bridge. As Batman said while breaking his rule in Batman #420 (1988): Sometimes you have to ignore the rules. I'm not in this business to protect the rules, I serve justice. Since there's also too many instances showing Batman occasionally killing since the late 60's, here are just a few more examples:

**Detective Comics #29**
[image]

**Detective Comics #33. He throws a vial of sleeping gas at the pilot who crashes into a river**

[image]

There are a lot more examples like that in comics.

In **Nolan's trilogy** itself total deaths caused by Batman is approximately 10:

In Batman Begins, the explosive chain reaction that Bruce started caused many deaths (8 onscreen) but they most likely weren't intended. Bruce wanted to have a distraction to escape and weaken the League of Shadow ninjas, but the fire caused more than he counted on.

[image]

By the end of the movie Batman lets Ra's Al Ghul die by leaving him in a racing train whose controls has been disabled

In The Dark Knight Batman saves Joker from certain death but soon after kills Two-Face by throwing him and himself off the edge.

[image]

This is apparently an unplanned kill as well. Two-Face was standing close to the edge and Batman jumped at him trying to stop him from killing Gordon's son. He only had one hand to hold on and one to grab the boy.

Comment: He's not called the `Dark Knight` for nothing!

Comment: I like the Detective Comics #33 one. The guy’s dead and Bruce Wayne is just puffing away on his pipe.

Comment: Yeah that one is interesting, like a cold blooded killer of Burton's Movies.